# How to set a reminder and alarm at the same time

Tags: ios, sleep-wake, notifications, reminders, alarm

How can I set a reminder to send me a notification at the same time the first ou a specific alarm goes of?

What I am trying to do is, I have to take a medicine everyday in the morning, but I wake up at a different time everyday. So I wanted to have a notification "Take the Med" when I wake up.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: all we have to do is tell our IOS when you are awake.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you use iPhone to wake you up that should do it. choose one http://appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-wake-up-message

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an alarm in the clock app and add a custom label to it.

You can also setup a scheduled task in the Reminders app which can be repeated. It can be setup that if you leave a location without checking the box that the reminder is complete you will get a notification. It can also be setup with an alarm for a specific time.